# Roll Back policy to previous version for an IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to roll back to a previous version of the policy for an IAM role?
I mistakenly made changes to the production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such thing as policy versioning: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-versioning.html

Also, you might want to consider "infra as code" frameworks, such as [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) to keep your code (including IAM policies) under code versioning control

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you are going via user or role, go to IAM console, select user (or Role) and go to summary page, then click the policy name in the "Permission" tab.

Then in Policy summary page, select "Policy versions" tab. There, you can set the previous policy as default or you can delete away your changes (wrong policy version).